# Referring to center x/y point from UIButton is not correct

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield, centering

I am trying to programmatically make an UITextField that is: in the center of the UIButton and has the same width. When the user clicks the button, the text should pop up. This is what I got so far:

```
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let centerXPointForSender = sender.center.x
    let centerYPointForSender = sender.center.y
    let animatingScoreText = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: centerXPointForSender, y: centerYPointForSender, width: 300, height: 40))
    animatingScoreText.minimumFontSize = 8
    animatingScoreText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    animatingScoreText.font = UIFont(name: "Damascus", size: 30)
    animatingScoreText.textColor = UIColor.cyan
    animatingScoreText.text = "Well hello"
    animatingScoreText.textAlignment = .center
    view.addSubview(animatingScoreText)
}
```

The width should not be that 300 but the buttons width. However, the text is appearing too far to the right? If you can make a project with a button that will execute above code, you will get exactly the same problem. What is wrong with this code? When printing the Y position of the button and text, it is also different.

Am I misunderstanding how setting the origin of the frame with the `x:` and `y:` impacts the position relative to the center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the button and the text field will have the same parent view, the easiest would be to do:

```
var frame = sender.frame
frame.size.height = 40
frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + (sender.frame.size.height - frame.size.height) / 2
let animatingScoreText = UITextField(frame: frame)
```

This gives the text field the same frame as the button except for the different height centered in the button's height.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am dealing with one problem. The textfield is now placed correctly in the middle of the button. However, this is for the X position. The button is still placed at the far top of the button. When I am printing the Y value's, they are printing the same value. How can it be that the button is not correctly placed in the middle of the button, with the correct Y value? The button is a play card, with an image of a random card. The button is in a subview of the View. However, this wouldn't matter right? Do you know why this problem occurs?

Comment: Does the button and the text view have the same parent view? What is the height of the button? The code I posted should center the text field over the button. Did you copy my code or type it in? You might have a typo.

Comment: No, and that was the case. Very stupid! Well thank you very much for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are initializing your `UITextField` you are setting the ***origin*** to the center of the button.  The origin refers to the upper left corner, which is why your textfield is showing up to the right.

In other words, you are telling the UITextField to be placed in the view with the upper left corner in the center of the button.

If you want the textField to be in the same position as the button change to:

```
UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: sender.frame.origin.x, y: sender.frame.origin.y, width: 300, height: 40))
```

This assumes that the button's superview is the same as the UITextField's superview.

If the `UITextField` is supposed to be in the exact same position as the button you could even simplify this by saying:

```
UITextField(frame: sender.frame)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you see the comment I made above to the other answer? There is still one little problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Petravd1994 OK, yes, it does matter that the button is in a subview of the main view.  `frame` refers to the coordinates within the view's superview's coordinate system.  This means that you need to find what the coordinates are in the textField's superview's coordinate system.  You have 2 options.  You can either calculate the correct point with math or using `convertPoint...`, or you can just add the textField as a subview of the same view your button is a subview of.

Comment: So if the view your button is in is called "buttonContainerView" (as an example) you could just change `view.addSubView(animatingScoreText)` to `buttonContainerView.addSubview(animatingScoreText)`.  Does this make sense?

Comment: Exactly! That was not working every well. This also answered a question from my programming mate: stackoverflow.com/questions/42121814/ It is weird that sender.frame is working differently than adding the constrains in that question. I would like to give you credits as well. If you post this answer to that question, I will make sure your answer there gets chosen as the best answer (since Rmaddy was slight earlier). Just post there this answer and I will say it to my mate. Thank you!!

Comment: @Petravd1994 Thanks - I can't really understand your friend's question, but hopefully you are able to help him now.